# Finding (x, y) pairs that share at least one x or y point

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following list:

```
[[452, 268],
 [303, 181],
 [452, 331],
 [378, 217],
 [572, 476],
 [464, 218],
 [42, 440],
 [428, 476],
 [42, 36],
 [478, 35],
 [232, 275],
 [428, 440],
 [378, 36],
 [572, 35]]
```

One can see that there exists pairs that share either the same x or y point, for example the first element `[452, 268]` and the third `[452, 331]` share the same x point.

What would be the optimal way to create an array with elements of the form `[x1 y1 x2 y2]` where two of one of points `x1 y1 x2 y2` are equal. So essentially I would like to loop through all the (x,y) points and determine if they share at least one equal element and combine them into `[x1 y1 x2 y2]`.

My idea was to loop through the whole list and compare the consecutive tuples, but I couldn't find any good way to approach this. I tried also to find if `itertools` would have had any helpers for this, but without luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sample output of given input ?

Comment: You could feed each column into a Counter and then only compare pairs where `x` or `y` show up at least twice. This would keep the complexity of comparing pairs, but reduce the number of pairs to compare.

Comment: @ZainArshad For example from `[452, 268]` and `[452, 331]` the output of the form `[452, 268, 452, 331]` should work.

Comment: @Nate why not use tuples, or nested lists even? `[452, 268, 452, 331]` isn't very intuitive, what would be the result for `[452, 268]`, `[452, 331]` and `[404, 268]`?

Comment: Ah good point missed to describe that. There shouldn't be any more than 4 elements in the output list. So for `[452, 268]`, `[452, 331]` and `[404, 268]` the output should be all possible combinations of the three that would share a point, but if one would loop through all the pairs shouldn't this be achieved either way?

Comment: So the output for that example would be `[[452, 268, 452, 331], [452, 268, 404, 268]]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question. This will print all combination of points where they share one common coordinate (x or y):

```
points = [[452, 268],
 [303, 181],
 [452, 331],
 [378, 217],
 [572, 476],
 [464, 218],
 [42, 440],
 [428, 476],
 [42, 36],
 [478, 35],
 [232, 275],
 [428, 440],
 [378, 36],
 [572, 35]]


from pprint import pprint
from itertools import combinations, chain

x_points, y_points = {}, {}
for p in points:
    x_points.setdefault(p[0], []).append(p)
    y_points.setdefault(p[1], []).append(p)

out = []

for p in x_points.values():
    for c in combinations(p, 2):
        out.append(list(chain(*c)))

for p in y_points.values():
    for c in combinations(p, 2):
        out.append(list(chain(*c)))


pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[452, 268, 452, 331],
 [378, 217, 378, 36],
 [572, 476, 572, 35],
 [42, 440, 42, 36],
 [428, 476, 428, 440],
 [572, 476, 428, 476],
 [42, 440, 428, 440],
 [42, 36, 378, 36],
 [478, 35, 572, 35]]
```

---

For `points = [[452, 268], [452, 331],[404, 268]]`:

The result is:

```
[[452, 268, 452, 331], [452, 268, 404, 268]]
```